# Determine what the last number in this series is

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

> 4, 23, 20, 12, 14, 9, 20, 19, ?

Also explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> 9

because

> In the title of the question, the words begin with DWTLNITSI, corresponding to positions 4, 23, 20, 12, 14, 9, 20, 19, 9 in the alphabet.

Comment: We have a winner!

Answer (score -1):

> 4, 23, 20, 12, 14, 9, 20, 19, ?
>   19, -3, -8, 2, -5, 11, -1, ?
>   -22, -5, -6, -7, -16, -12, ?
>   17, -1, -1, -9, 4, ?
>   -18, 0, -8, 13, ?
>   18, -8, 21, ?
>   -26, 29, ?
>   45, ?

We can achieve that by using a difference table. Then starting by the bottom we can work out way up by replacing the first "?" with another 45:

> 4, 23, 20, 12, 14, 9, 20, 19, 118
>   19, -3, -8, 2, -5, 11, -1, 99
>   -22, -5, -6, -7, -16, -12, 100
>   17, -1, -1, -9, 4, 112
>   -18, 0, -8, 13, 108
>   18, -8, 21, 95
>   -26, 29, 74
>   45, 45

So the next number in the sequence is 118. Making the full sequence:

> 4, 23, 20, 12, 14, 9, 20, 19, 118

*That is unless I made a mistake calculating*

**Note: This may not be the answer you're looking for, and I get that, but it doesn't make this answer any less correct; so please do not downvote.**

Comment: This is an interesting answer, although definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @pac It's still noneoftheless correct though.

Comment: @pac Did you upvote it?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it can be done for any finite sequence of numbers, and so it can apply to nearly any question. I don't think it's interesting after seeing it the first time. Usually there's a more meaningful answer.

Comment: @pac I'm not begging for votes, I was wondering if you were the one that gave me the upvote.

Comment: @Envision True, but it's still valid, and technically correct, do I enjoy using it on "what's the next number in the sequence..." type questions, just to show there can be more than one answer. Technically should this kind of question be too broad? I could make the next number anything and be able to verify it.

Comment: @warspyking typically for a well made "what's the next number" question, there is a single answer which fits significantly better than any others.

Comment: @frodo Yes I suppose, but that doesn't change the fact that there could be infinite answers. Also the "correct" answer is primarily opinion based

Comment: @war yes, there could be infinite answers. My point is that what distinguishes a **good** question of this type is that there is a single answer which can be generally agreed to be by far the best fit. If the answer, when revealed, is not obviously correct to most readers I would argue that it is a "read my mind" question.

Comment: The difference between negative 8 and positive 2 is not negative 6. It's Positive 10.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you can then get another number in the series after 118.  As the question was asked, there is a definitive *last* number, which we are asked to provide.  This is a big difference between this an classic "find the next number in this sequence" questions, and also a clue that the answer is probably not math based. Your series goes on infinitely, so there is no last number, so it is not a correct answer to the question IMHO.